# How can i bypass the request of Hardware Virtualization

Tags: macos

When I use VMWare8 to work with installing MAC OS 10.7.3,It tell me there is a request about Hardware Virtualization.In old VMWare versions like VMWare7,My friend uses some tools to bypass the Hardware Virtualization but I didn't see how to do it.
   Now ,as I konw ,the some tools may be `vmware-vmx-patch-(x32).exe` and I think other tools may be needed.Can any guy tell me how to slove this problem? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not easy to solve ,because OSX is newest.